# How to put Bokeh legend on the 'bottom_right'

Tags: python, bokeh, roc

I am trying to produce an ROC curve using Bokeh. I have the following code that used to run before, but now I get an error saying: ValueError: invalid value: 'bottom_right'; allowed values are horizontal or vertical

```
p = figure(title='ROC Curve: Logistic Regression', width=800, height=800)

p.line(x=fpr, y=tpr, legend='ROC Curve: Area Under Curve = %0.3f' %roc_auc)
p.legend.orientation = 'bottom_right'
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'False Positive Rate'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'True Positive Rate'
show(p)
```

All I want to do is to put the legend at the bottom of the screen so it won't cover part of the curve. Can anyone advise please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set `location`, not `orientation`

```
p.legend.location = 'bottom_right'
```

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#location